# Why WebCryptoAPI RSA-OAEP encrypt function is unable to use the expected maximum chunk size for a given key size?

Tags: encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api

I am trying use the `crypto.subtle.encrypt` to encrypt some data and ran into trouble for the amount of data I can encrypt at a time. The maximum block size for a 2048-bit key using RSA-OAEP is 214Bytes, as indicated in links [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32692/what-is-the-typical-block-size-in-rsa) and  [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822607/what-is-the-rsa-max-block-size-to-encode) using the relation `maxChunkSizeInBytes = keySizeInBytes – 42`.

Using `crypto.subtle.encrypt` with a 2048-bit key and the RSA-OAEP algorithm,  I am only able to encrypt 190 Bytes. Any amount below 190 Bytes works fine and any above 190 Bytes results in an error. I am not entirely sure the type of error (since I am unable to catch it), but I think its an `OperationError` , reference [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt).

In the TypeScript example shown here there are two data chunks `d1` and `d2` with sizes 190 Bytes and 214 Bytes respectively. The data block `d1` encrypts fine, however, `d2`  does not.

```
const MSG_LEN_1 = 190;
const MSG_LEN_2 = 214;

const d1 = (window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(MSG_LEN_1))).buffer;
const d2 = (window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(MSG_LEN_2))).buffer;

let encData = async (data: ArrayBuffer) => {
    const key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );
    const enc = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {
              name: "RSA-OAEP"
            },
            key.publicKey,
            data
          );
    return enc;
};

encData(d1).then(
    (enc : ArrayBuffer) => {
        alert("Success working on d1");
    }
);

encData(d2).then(
    (enc : ArrayBuffer) => {
            alert("Success working on d2");
    }
);
```

On compiling and running the above TypeScript in Firefox and Chrome (by including in a simple html page) I notice an `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` error in the developer console after the first alert.

Is there something I am missing when using `crypto.subtle.encrypt` or incorrectly using the RSA-OAEP algorithm?

Comment: May be I am using the wrong relationship, should I be using `maxChunkSizeInBytes = keySizeInBytes  - hashSizeInBytes * 2 – 2` so for a 2048-bit key with a SHA-256 hash its `2048/8-256/8*2-2=190` Bytes ?

Comment: Exactly, the size of a SHA-256 hash is 256 bits / 32 bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula `modulus size - 2 - 2*hash size`, it is working properly for SHA256 (32 bytes). Seem you are applying SHA1 size(20 bytes)

- SHA256: `256 - 2 - 2*32  = 190`
- SHA1:  `256 - 2 - 2*20  = 214`

Comment: Yes, just tested the example with SHA-512 and the maximum size was 126Bytes . Thanks!